# Admin grid for custom Model

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, router

I am making a module with a custom grid I am getting stuck on the router why am I getting a 404?

`config.xml`:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml
                    </modulename>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

`adminhtml.xml`:

```
<menu>
    <sales>
        <children>
            <modulename translate="title" module="namespace_modulename">
                <title>Modulename</title>
                <action>adminhtml/modulename</action>
                <sort_order>40</sort_order>
            </modulename>
        </children>
    </sales>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <sales>
                    <children>
                        <modulename>
                            <title>Modulename</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/modulename</action>
                        </modulename>
                    </children>
                </sales>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```